# Webpack: what are modules with no loaders? How to optimize them?

Tags: webpack

I'm using `speed-measure-webpack-plugin` to measure the performance of my Webpack builds, and something is mysterious to me : when cold booting my dev build, I see that `modules with no loaders` is by far the most common type of module, and also the type of module that takes the longest to process :

```
 SMP  ⏱  Loaders
modules with no loaders took 48.51 secs
  module count = 2963
typings-for-css-modules-loader, and
postcss-loader, and
less-loader took 41.81 secs
  module count = 95
ts-loader took 39.55 secs
  module count = 488
babel-loader took 4.12 secs
  module count = 4
css-loader, and
postcss-loader took 3.91 secs
  module count = 1
url-loader took 1.13 secs
  module count = 10
pegjs-loader took 0.723 secs
  module count = 2
style-loader, and
typings-for-css-modules-loader, and
postcss-loader, and
less-loader took 0.157 secs
  module count = 95
html-webpack-plugin took 0.045 secs
  module count = 1
style-loader, and
css-loader, and
postcss-loader took 0.002 secs
  module count = 1
```

My questions are: what exactly are modules with no loaders? Is there a way to list all those modules with no loaders so I can see where they come from, and what can be done about them?

I'm suspecting they come from `node_modules` dependencies, but I'm not sure what to do about it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after removing the `include` option in this rule of the webpack config :

```
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        // include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
```

I was able to have no modules with no loaders, so I assume they were all vanilla JS files from `node_modules`.

However, to my disappointment, this actually *slowed* my build:

```
 SMP  ⏱  Loaders
babel-loader took 1 min, 0.222 secs
  module count = 2946
typings-for-css-modules-loader, and
postcss-loader, and
less-loader took 41.55 secs
  module count = 95
ts-loader took 35.4 secs
  module count = 488
css-loader, and
postcss-loader took 26.68 secs
  module count = 12
modules with no loaders took 5.18 secs
  module count = 10
url-loader took 1.69 secs
  module count = 25
pegjs-loader took 0.597 secs
  module count = 2
style-loader, and
typings-for-css-modules-loader, and
postcss-loader, and
less-loader took 0.104 secs
  module count = 95
html-webpack-plugin took 0.025 secs
  module count = 1
style-loader, and
css-loader, and
postcss-loader took 0.009 secs
  module count = 12
```

I don't believe there is a way to actually optimize this...

Comment: Your hunch is almost certainly right - the files are `node_modules` js files. When you removing the `include` you're telling babel-loader it needs to operate on these files. That takes time but is unnecessary because .js files in node_modules should be ready to import directly.

`modules with no loaders` itself is not a bad thing. It just means files that webpack reads directly with no processing needed.

You may have too much content in your `node_modules`. You could use [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to take a look at your bundle content.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to list all those modules with no loaders?

Yes, you can tell the `speed-measure-webpack-plugin` to show the top n modules that are the slowest in each category using the [`loaderTopFiles`](https://github.com/stephencookdev/speed-measure-webpack-plugin#optionsloadertopfiles) option. This will show you which modules they are.